# TypeError: ‘NoneType’ object is not callable while use the model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, classification

I’m using PyTorch for training CNN, I have a simple model that saved using this command:

```
class_index = ['female', 'male']

class Predictor():
    def __init__(self, class_index):
        self.class_index = class_index
    
    def predict_max(self, output):
        max_id = np.argmax(output.detach().numpy())
        predicted_label = self.class_index(max_id)
        return predicted_label


predictor = Predictor(class_index)
img = Image.open('./test.jpg')
img = img.convert("RGB")

def predict(img):
    # prepare network
    model = CNN()
    print("model:", model)
    model.eval()

    # prepare model
    trained_model = load_model(model, save_path)
    print("trained_model:", trained_model)

    # prepare input img
    transform = ImageTransform(resize, mean, std)
    img = transform(img, phase="test")
    img = img.unsqueeze_(0)

    # predict
    output = trained_model(img)
    response = predictor.predict_max(output)

    return response
```

But then when I tried to input the data as follows:

```
predict(img)
```

I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\long1\OneDrive\Máy tính\Gender_Classification\main.py", line 267, in <module>
    predict(img)
  File "C:\Users\long1\OneDrive\Máy tính\Gender_Classification\main.py", line 262, in predict
    output = trained_model(img)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Why is this happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: The `load_model` method is returning `None`. Check the function.

Comment: More than likely `load_model` modifies `model` in-place and does not return anything, so the appropriate call is simply `load_model(model,save_path)`

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems line trained_model object is getting Null value.
Debug this line trained_model = load_model(model, save_path) and see if object  get stored in trained_model